# Xamarin Android BottomNavigationView adds a blank area to right side

Tags: android, layout, xamarin.android, bottomnavigationview

Just started a Xamarin.Android project using an up to date VS 2019. Seemed fine until I added a 4th bottom tab, then suddenly I got a blank space to the right. I would appreciate any help in removing it.

[image]

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/message"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:text="@string/title_search" />

  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
     android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/navigation_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_search" />

  <item android:id="@+id/navigation_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_favorite" />

  <item android:id="@+id/navigation_recent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_recent_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_recent" />

  <item android:id="@+id/navigation_support"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_support_black_24dp"
      android:title="@string/title_support" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BottomNavigationView` has a `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, meaning it will take the minimum amount of horizontal space possible, leaving any additional space empty. If you want it to extend from edge to edge, you need to use `android:layout_width="match_parent"`